# Gatsby plugin - onCreateNode is not called for all created nodes

Tags: typescript, gatsby

I'm struggling with onCreateNode call in my gatsby plugin. The plugin is responsible for fetching data from backend and creating an apropriate nodes.

Plugin is written in TS, related fragments:

```
export const sourceNodes: GatsbyNode["sourceNodes"] = async ({
    actions,
    createContentDigest,
    createNodeId,
    }) => {
    try {
        const { createNode } = actions;

        for (const lang of languages) {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://mybackend.com/backend/${lang}/api/pages`,
            {}
        );
        let pages = await response.json();
        //remove nulls
        pages = JSON.stringify(pages, ({}, value) => {
            if (value === null) {
            return "";
            }
            return value;
        });
        pages = JSON.parse(pages);

        for (const page of pages) {
            const pageNode = {
            ...page,
            templateName: getName(page),
            lang: lang,
            id: createNodeId(`${PAGE_NODE_TYPE}-${lang}-${page.url}`), // hashes the inputs into an ID
            parent: null,
            children: [],
            internal: {
                type: PAGE_NODE_TYPE,
                contentDigest: createContentDigest(page),
            },
            };
            await createNode(pageNode);
        }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }

    console.log("source nodes end");
    return;
}


export const onCreateNode: GatsbyNode["onCreateNode"] = async ({
node,
actions,
createNodeId,
getCache,
}) => {
    console.log("On create node");
    console.log(node.internal.type);
    if (node.internal.type === PAGE_NODE_TYPE) {
        await createImage(node, actions, createNodeId, getCache, "sm_header_image");
        await createImage(node, actions, createNodeId, getCache, "md_header_image");
        await createImage(node, actions, createNodeId, getCache, "lg_header_image");
    }
};
```

The onCreateNode is not called for PAGE_NODE_TYPE. Why?

The onCreateNode is called for different node.internal.types, so the hook is registered correctly.

It seems to work fine if I split this calls into two different plugins.